# Is there a way to bind a Dictionary in mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

I started using observable ConcurrentDictionary because it's threadsafe. But now I face a problem how to bind it to the list.

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SourceDictionary"
```

obviously cannot work because item consists of the KeyValuePair and not the object itself.

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SourceDictionary.Values"
```

does not work. Which, I must admit, puzzles me.
I even tried a long shot and did some converter :

```
public class SourceDictionaryValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<KeyValuePair<string, SourceClass >, SourceClass >
{
    protected override SourceClass Convert(KeyValuePair<string, SourceClass> value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

and bind it like this

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SourceDictionary, Converter=SourceDictionary"
```

but it didn't work. I suppose it asks for IList. 
Is there any way to bind ListView to the Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bind to a Dictionary - or indeed to any `IEnumerable`.

If you are binding to the Dictionary itself (rather than to `Values`) then you will need to write your item bindings so that they know about KeyValuePair - e.g. so you might need to bind to `Key.Name` rather than to just `Name`.

However, Dictionary's themselves do *not* notify listeners of changes - so using a Dictionary is like using a List - not like using an ObservableCollection. If you want this type of behaviour then you will need to write or find a Dictionary class which implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: I used ObservableConcurrentDictionary that i found on github, it  works but I still dont get binding itself.Let's suppose that there is ListItemViewModel with public property Name and in MainViewModel there is public property ObservableConcurrentDictionary<string, ListItemViewModel> VMList. When I bind ListView in MainView to the VMList it shows empty items. So problem is in ListItemView bindings. Binding to Key.Name dont work and frankly I don't get it. How shold <TextView local:MvxBind="Text Key.Name"> work? ListItemViewModel doesnt know of property Key. I'm sure that I messed something up:(

Comment: My bad. One Async too much :( Dictionary.Values does the trick. Thnx on your help